# R - how to find image elements inside a mask in a time series of images?

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array, indexing, nifti

My R script loads a 4-dimensional data set which is a time series of 3D medical images. I use the time series to create a mask for excluding voxels (3-dimensional pixels) that have the value 0 at every time point:

```
voxels[is.na(voxels)]=0;             # just get rid of unusable data
mask=rowSums(voxels,dims=3);         # 3D image that is the sum over time
mask=(mask!=0);                      # make binary
```

So to find the values for each time point at the indices inside the mask I want to do:

```
indices=which(mask!=0);              # find the positions of nonzeroes in the mask
voxelsfound=voxels[indices];         # find the values in the images at those positions
```

but that gives

```
 > length(indices)
 [1] 20483
 > length(voxelsfound)
 [1] 20483
```

so only the result for the first time point. Is there a similar way to formulate this so that it returns the other time points as well (my idea was `voxelsfound=voxels[indices,]` but that does not work), or is it only possible with a for loop or similar?

In Python I would do something like this (using `m` for `mask` and `v` for `voxels`), using the `nonzero` function for immediate access to the indices:

```
m = m.reshape(np.prod(m.shape));    
v = v.reshape(np.prod(m.shape),v.shape[3]);
v = v[:,np.nonzero(m)].squeeze();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
mask <- which(rowSums(voxels, dims=3) != 0, arr.ind=T)
apply(voxels, 4, `[`, mask)
```

Comment: Brilliant - that's exactly it! It doesn't look like something that should work though, an opening bracket without closing?

Comment: Well, note the backticks around the bracket – they're important and indicate that the bracket is _quoted_ (so not subject to the usual syntax rules of bracket-matching, but treated as a symbol instead).  Basically, `\`[\`` is the name of the primitive used to subscript, in the sense that `x[1]` and `\`[\`(x, 1)` are equivalent (likewise with `\`[[\``).

Comment: In other words, you could also write something like `apply(voxels, 4, function (voxel) voxel[mask])`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. In your example is it 4 (not 3) because indexing starts at 0? The mask variable itself is a 3d array.

Comment: Hey, indexing starts at 1!  Basically, what the code does is goes over the 4th dimension ("time"), resulting in a sequence of 3d arrays which are each subscripted by the mask and then put back together.  This is how you would write the "intuitive" `voxels[indices, ]` in R.

Comment: Thanks again -- still getting used to the notation. I guess I was thrown by `dims=3` in the `rowSums` command, assuming that indicated the dimension to sum along. Just read about the interpretation of dims in `rowSums` *(dims+1)* and `colSums` *(1:dims)*. All clear now.